# 'Just because I think doesn't mean I know how to think'- Rambam quote?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, quotations

A few years ago I heard Rabbi Joseph Dweck give a lecture on Kabalah and he mentioned this quotation attributed to Rambam: "Just because I think doesn't mean I know how to think." But I haven't been able to find it using Rabbi Google and Sepharia. Does anyone know the source?

Comment: Is the class available online by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

I asked Rabbi Dweck via Instagram and he said it was actually his own quote summing up the opening of Moreh Nevuchim

Comment: :) Good one. Thanks for updating.